# Javascript simplifier?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, node.js, minify

I would like to eliminate functions that are unused or not related to the given context. Let's say we have:

```
function a(){ console.log('this is an unrelated function'); }
function b(){ console.log('world'); }
function c(){ console.log('hello' + b()); }
c();
```

Now `a()` is not used at all, and I don't need it, it just makes the script bigger. And this is actually the case with `jQuery` too. I'm not sure if I need that much code as jQuery has. I'm using jQuery only for `highcharts` and to select elements from the dom by id and class, but it would be really good to get rid of the unused functions because jQuery is just simply too big!

Are there online tools, services, functions/methods, apps that can do this minification?

Comment: While it's not quite this advanced, Google's Closure Tools can do an aggressive minification.  Also, for a smaller jQuery, you might check out Zepto.js

Comment: Relevant link for Google's Closure Compiler service http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home

Comment: @jqueryrocks: advanced minification actually can do this (if properly setup).  However, I wish there was a "compiler" that did something like that, but didn't remove whitespace, change names, etc. - *that* would be really cool.

Comment: This is EXTREMELY difficult to do in Javascript, since the language is so dynamic.  Your function `a` could be called through some rather non-obvious ways.

Comment: Find some time and do a refactor. Then for a confidence boost, run your unit tests :)

Answer (score 2):

[Google Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) is a JavaScript optimizer. Its an useful tool that might be combined with other [Google Closure Tools](https://developers.google.com/closure/).

You can use the Closure Compiler as:

- An open source Java application that you can run from the command line.
- A simple web application.
- A RESTful API.

*Dead code removal* with [Google Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/):

> Compilation with `ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS` removes code that is provably unreachable. This is especially useful in combination with large libraries. If you use only a few functions from a large library file, the compiler can remove everything except those functions from its output.

The above paragraph were extracted from Closure Compiler [Docs reference](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/compilation_levels).

Comment: Might I just add this URL to the online version of it. [Closure Compiler Service](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home)